# Yii Unit-Testing with a Logged in Web User

Tags: php, yii, phpunit

Im writing some unit tests and bear with me I am still very new to unit testing.

The issue I am having is a lot of my saves invoke a behaviour that requires
the users id from `Yii::app()->user->id`.

However when I run the UnitTest I get problems as the user isn't logged in.

Is there anyway I can either ignore the behaviour by a flag (e.g. `if ($isInTestingMode)`) or log the user in within the testing class?

Comment: The way I would do this is have a set of tests for the logged in users, and another set for non-logged in users, with the difference being in the setup methods, where one includes code to log the user in . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably build a user object that you use in your tests.  And then in the appropriate tests (as part of the `setup` method, like ernie describes in his comment), swap in the testing user object.

The test user object would then have a method that works like this:

```
public function getId() {
    return 12;
}

public function getIsGuest() {
    return false;
}
```

The above is what they call a 'Fake' object.

In your setup method you'd use the following lines:

```
Yii::app()->configure(array(
    'components' => array(
        'user' => array(
            'class' => 'path.to.FakeUser',
        )
    )
));
```

You can also add that to your test config file if you want that to be the default user (and then swap in the normal `CWebUser/WebUser` model in tests that need to have a non-logged in user.

Or you could have a flag you set for your FakeUser (isLoggedIn = true/false) in each unit test.  I'd probably go with this option myself ...

Answer (score 3):

Tests like these are not unit tests. Unit tests are for testing individual functions in a class. A "logged in user" covers a large swath of code (logging in, session management, navigating to a specific page, etc.). I believe you're looking for functional testing. You can learn more about that here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.functional

Comment: That being said, how would you *unit test* a single method in which a call to user->id is made?

Comment: You would test how that property is used. For example, if the method returns the output of `user->id` you would check that your value of `user->id` matches the return value. Or if the function uses that value in another function call, you could stub the second function being called and check that it is called with the argument you expect.